# How can i access a dictionary from a python file (using python)

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have this file named "names.py"

```
names = {}

names['males']=[
  "Bob",
  "Will",
  "John"
]
names['female']=[
  "Anna",
  "Lindsay",
  "Nicole",
]
```

i also have this other .py file named "income.py"

```
exec(open("names.py").read())
print(names["males"])
```

But this isn't working. It sais there is no "names" variable.
Does anyone know how to do it? It must be 2 differently files.

Comment: Why cannot you import your names file?

Comment: You need to import another module. Read [6. Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Are you sure the two files are in the same directory? The provided code works as described.

Comment: exec is a terrible way to learn things because it can be misused to execute untrustworthy files in the future. Anyhow, Dmitry is right. Code works as described. Make sure names file is in the same directory where `income.py` file is.

Comment: I´m sure they are in the same directory. When i run it it gives me this message: NameError: name 'names' is not defined

Comment: @DiogoMiranda - How are you running this? names.py puts `names` in its global namespace and your `exec` call uses your global namespace as the executed file's namespace. So, `names` should be available to the calling script.

Comment: Please _never_ use `exec` or `eval` unless you (a) _really_ need to (you almost certainly don't) and (b) you fully understand the security implications.

Answer (score 0):

Filelord alludes to how you might do this with an import statement.  Picking up on his comment, here is one possible way when "names.py" is in the same folder/directory.

```
import names

print(names.names['males'])
```

When I executed this program, this is what printed on my terminal.

```
['Bob', 'Will', 'John']
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Regards.